# How to query on a method value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Consider this table:**

```
create_table "liquor_lots", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "recipe_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.integer "counter"
end
```

**And the resulting model**

```
class LiquorLot < ApplicationRecord
 def lotcode
    "#{recipe_id}#{created_at.strftime("%y")}#{created_at.strftime("%W")}#{created_at.strftime("%u")}"
  end
  
  def pallet_lotcode
    "#{lotcode}-#{counter}"
  end
end
```

I'd like to do the equivalent of this in SQL:
`Select distinct(lotcode) from liquor_lots`

I've tried this and it understandably fails because `lotcode` is not a column on the `liquor_lots` table.  But I've always been advised against adding columns to store data that is derived from data in other columns.

**So how do I search for those values?**

For context, my `lotcode` actually consists of many more values concatenated together, I just limited to three in the example for readability.

Comment: Hi!
I would perform a custom query: `LiquorLot.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT ...sql concatenations here... AS lotcode FROM liquorlots...")`. I apologize for not ellaborating more, it is very late here but tomorrow I'll try to give a better answer.
Also it is not neccesary to concatenate all those strftime calls. You can do it in one shot like this: `created_at.strftime('%y%W%u')`

Comment: Thanks for the strftime recommendation.  That will simplify my code (both in the method and the query).

Comment: May I ask what RDBMS are you using? Is it postgres?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, with basic ActiveRecord you cannot do that.
ActiveRecord would have to know too much about your ruby code.

You could implement a SQL query that concatenates the relevant values by hand (see comment to your question).

Or you can query all objects (or just the relevant values using `pluck()`) and then work on that with standard Ruby Array/Enumerable methods (in memory). If the application is not performance-critical, happens rarely, and you do not have thousands of the liquor_lots, that would be an okay productivity-tradeoff in my eyes.

Besides storing it in an own column, you could also extract the codes in separate table and make `PalletLotcode` an entity of its own. `LiquorLots` would than `belong_to` a single `PalletLotcode` which would `have_many` `LiquorLots`. But compared to the separate column this is a rather complex operation, but makes sense if other information is to be stored on the Lotcodes.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to add the query to the mode using scope, or in the controller?

Comment: I lack details - it depends on the purpose, the code etc. Depending on the complexity I would put it in an own class or if the model is slim and its one of the most common thing you ask it I would put it in the model.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like:

```
LiquorLot.where("recipe_id = :rcp_id AND created_at >= :begin_of_day AND created_at <= :end_of_day", {begin_of_day: calculate_begin_of_day, end_of_day: calculate_end_of_date, rcp_id: id})
```

*calculate_begin_of_day* and *calculate_end_of_date* can be implemented using [Date.comercial](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial) method and Date.beginning_of_day and Date.end_of_day

Comment: While this simplifies the date query part, the original question was explicitely about the derived `pallet_lotcode` property of the objects.